# Can't include a reference with BibTex

Tags: biblatex, xetex, pdftex

I want to include a reference. For this purpose, I create a file called References.bib in which I put this:

```
 @article{ref,
   author={First author, Second Author and Third author},
   title={Title of the article},
   journal={},
   year = 2005
 }
```

Then in the latex file I include the refrence by:

```
 \cite{ref}
```

I also include in the beginning:

```
  \usepackage{natbib}
  \usepackage{cite}
```

And at the end before the end document:

```
 \bibliographystyle{te}
 \bibliography{References}
```

I get a question mark instead of the reference.
I don't know what's wrong with my code ?
Thank you in advance !!

Comment: The sequence is `latex <file>`, `bibtex <file>`, `latex <file>`, `latex <file>` where "<file>" is the name of the `.tex` file (and `.aux` file in the case of BibTeX, but note that the extension does not need to be declared explicitly).  There are many questions/answers on this site that explain in more detail.

Comment: For multiple authors, you should write `author={First author and Second Author and Third author}`.

Comment: I think I have a problem with the te.bst style file. Is it obligatory or I can omit it and have a style by default?

Comment: @jon I don't understand your response. But I still have the problem. I get a ? . Could you please helpe me.

Comment: Where is `te.bst` from? (You do want to specify a **B**ibliography **ST**yle file.) Do you get one ? or two ?? in your test document?

Comment: Does it work if you specify `plain` as the style? Suppose that `myfile.tex` is your tex file. Then you'd run `pdflatex myfile.tex`, then `bibtex myfile.aux`, then `pdflatex myfile.tex` and `pdflatex myfile.tex` to get the references resolved. (If you are using pdfLaTeX. If you are using a different engine, you'd use that instead of `pdflatex`.)

Comment: In fact: don't load both `cite` and `natbib` (says so in the `natbib` documentation).

Comment: Yes I have tried with plain but didn't work. the te.bst file I have downloaded it from internet

Comment: I removed the \usepackage{natbib}. However, I still get this [?] as a result.

Answer (score 2):

This works (except for the fact that you probably shouldn't be citing an "article" without a journal title...).  The thing to note is that you can use both `cite` and `natbib` at the same time, so pick one or the other.  This example uses `natbib`, but you can switch with `cite` if you like.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{ref,
%      author={First author, Second Author and Third author},
   author={First author and Second Author and Third author}, % <-- note also the consistent formatting of authors names (better still is to use "Lastname1, Firstname1 and Lastname2, Firstname2 and ..."
   title={Title of the article},
   journal={},
   year = 2005
 }
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{natbib}%
% \usepackage{cite}% <-- or switch with natbib

\begin{document}

\cite{ref}

\bibliographystyle{te}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

Remember to run:

```sh
latex file   # or: file.tex
bibtex file  # or: file.aux
latex file   # or: file.tex
latex file   # or: file.tex
```

to resolve your citations.

Comment: There is an improvement, now there is the References title added. But the citations are not there !!! I get this: Package natbib Warning: Citation `ref' on page 5 undefined on input line 185.

(./Reading note 3.bbl

Package natbib Warning: Empty `thebibliography' environment on input line 3.

)

Package natbib Warning: There were undefined citations.

Comment: I am using Texmaker. but even though there is still the above problem.

Comment: Are you using my exact example file?  It sounds like you are mixing yours and mine.  If you are, make sure you use the correct name for your `.bib` file.  Here I have `\bibliography{\jobname}` but you may want to use something like `References.bib` as in your original question.

Comment: yes I changed the \jobname to References but still doesn't work

Comment: "still doesn't work" is extremely vague, especially since you haven't provided a MWE of your own.  Do you mean the example file in my answer and doesn't work?  Do you mean your own file, which no one else has seen or can test?

Comment: The `author` field should be `author={First Author and Second Author and Third Author},`. The word `and` is reserved to separate authors, while the `,` is reserved to write a given author's name in `SurName`, FirstName` format.

Comment: @Othermane -- Note also Mico's comment about the author's names (not the source of your problem, but the way your example is setup, you'll get weird output for the authors' names).